# How to call angular scope function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i call some function in angular from javascript .
I have a main controller having function which i want to invoke from javascript code.
For example, in my controller file i have code like this

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http){
     //some code
     $scope.someFunction=function(value){
        // Need value to be accessed here
     } 
});
```

Now my code for calling to function is in **view.html** file, and at bottom im including **controller.js** . I have simply called method like this .
       `someFunction(value);`

Comment: Read the documentation on [Angular Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: in the button add the attribute ng-click="someFunction('value')"

Comment: You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. You will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some sort of directive - `ng-click`, `ng-init`, `ng-change`, etc. You can't access these bare functions outside the Angular scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it from inside the controller as follow:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http){
     //some code
     $scope.someFunction=function(value){
        // Need value to be accessed here
     } 

     $scope.someFunction(34); 
});
```

If you need to call it from another controller you can pass through a an event

```
// In your controller
$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, arg) {
     $scope.someFunction(arg);
});

....

// From the second controller
$scope.emit('myEvent', 34);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular directives to call your controller from your view.

For instance if you have a button in your view you could call a function defined in your controller and added to the scope.

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
     //some code
     $scope.someFunction=function(value){
        console.log('hello ' + value);
     } 
});
```

Your view.html

```
<a ng-click="someFunction('world')">Call</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the function from within the controller.See below, the last line in controller definition is the function call. It will invoke each time whecn the controller is called.

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$http){
     //some code
     $scope.someFunction=function(value){
        // Need value to be accessed here
     } 

$scope.someFunction();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

From inside your HTML page you have to execute the JavaScript after the page has finished loading.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
       //do work
     });
</script>
```

Once you have that you need to get your Angular module using your app name.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var app = angular.module('myApp');
     });
</script>
```

Once you have the module you can execute a run operation which will allow you to inject factories, services and constants. Things like controllers, directives and components are for HTML usage only.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var app = angular.module('myApp');
        app.run(['myService', function(myService) {
             // do your stuff here.
        });
     });
</script>
```

You can now share the `myService` data between the HTML page and your controller by also injecting `myService` into your controller.